# Assert json parameter value in second response with respect to same first request

Tags: json, jmeter, jsonassert

App is related to an f&b business, I have following scenarios (api calls):

1. **Create Order** - on creating an order of any food item (let it be X), inventory of which is updated at back-end (this value is under test, let it be P1)
2. **Get Inventory** - (this call will fetch me the updated value of inventory of ordered item (X) i.e. inventory value, P1)
3. **Cancel Order** - this will cancel the order, i created in my first call, and hence P1 should be rolled back.
4. **Get Inventory** - Again i will hit this call to get the value, so as to verify that the inventory value of P1 has been updated properly.

In API call, (2) I extract P1 value using [jp@gc Json Extractor](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) and same I did for same call (4). 
Now as per my expectations, value obtained in both these extractors should be equal as order has been cancelled now.

To assert these values, I am using [JSON Assertion](https://octoperf.com/blog/2018/04/19/jmeter-assertions/) , either I am making use of wrong assertion or lacking a big amount of information here.

May be there is something like I can save the value first in some variable, and then assert.

Image of my test suite:
[image]

Comment: The question isn't that clear. could you explain better or give example code of what you mean?

Comment: @kakigadol i just updated the same explaining more descriptively.

Comment: @kakigadol to be more precise, i am working for an F&B application, which has inventory managed at server side, and we create order from clients. so i need to test that while creating an order, is the inventory updated properly or not.

Comment: you need to check `p1` variable exists? do you want to stop execution? can you add more details?

Comment: @user7294900  i need to check the updated value of p1 from json extractors.
Let me add more information.

Comment: @kakigadol I have updated the complete information now, u can plese check if you can help. Let me know, if u need payloads also.

Comment: @user7294900 hey...i have added more description with image of my test suite. Please see if you can help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) with checking different variables e.g. `a` and `b`:

```
if (!vars.get("a").equals(vars.get("b"))) {
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("message");
     AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
}
```

> The script can check various aspects of the SampleResult. If an error is detected, the script should use AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("message") and AssertionResult.setFailure(true)

Comment: but how will i call the variable from extractor to this assertion?
Should i use syntax like for we do for json path, eg.: - $.extractingCriticalQuantity1

Comment: @abhinav use the **variable name**